# How to create a widget for kibana dashboard with ratio between distinct count

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, dashboard, kibana-4

I would like to create a widget in my  kibana dashboard to show the ratio (a number) between users (distinct count) and activities (count).
I can show the two different values in the same widget, but i rather to have only one value as result of activities\users.
I suppost that to use "scripted field" is not the best solution.
I don't know if [[Timelion](https://www.elastic.co/blog/timelion-timeline)] could be a solution.

Best regards

Alex

Comment: Perhaps Scripted field is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Timelion `.divide()` method. 
Example string can be `.es(metric='count: activities').divide(.es(metric='cardinality:users'))`